# Additional electric field due to changing magnetic field around a moving charge

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, point-particles

Imagine a point charge moving along x-axis in empty space at a constant velocity $v$. Since the charge is moving, the electric and magnetic field around it should be surmisable from this image (courtesy: brilliant.org)

[image: E/M field around a charge moving at constant velocity]

I suppose one can explain the shape of the above magnetic field from the following Maxwell's Equation:

$\nabla\times \boldsymbol{B} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t}$

The current component $\boldsymbol{J}$ is not needed since we have a lone charge moving in space.

If I understand the above equation correctly, the change w.r.t. time in $\boldsymbol{E}$ at any point in space is accompanied by $\boldsymbol{B}$ curling around it. Since the moving charge in our frame of reference concedes $\boldsymbol{E}$ at some points in space, and bolsters $\boldsymbol{E}$ at others, we see a concomitant curling $\boldsymbol{B}$ in proportion to the change in $\boldsymbol{E}$.

However, just like the diverging $\boldsymbol{E}$, the curling $\boldsymbol{B}$ is also changing w.r.t. time. Where is the accompanying $\boldsymbol{E}$ field that should arise due to the equation below?

$\nabla\times \boldsymbol{E} = -\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t}$

Why don't the authors usually comment on $\boldsymbol{E}$ accompanying the curling $\boldsymbol{B}$? I am assuming that there is no additional $\boldsymbol{E}$. Maybe, it's just that the curl of the already curling $\boldsymbol{B}$ is the original diverging $\boldsymbol{E}$, although moving in one direction. Am I correct? Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: The source term J is needed,  there is a current density, yes your equation holds for the space around the charge however this is not going to uniquely determine any shape without extra assumptions about the current density distribution

Comment: @jensen Hmm... it seems fair that our charge accounts for some J. But then my question would be: Is it the J or the partial derivative of E (or both) that accounts for the curl of magnetic field around the charge vicinity?

Comment: The time derivative of E describes the field-field interaction, and the current density is a charge-field interaction. Assuming any homogenous solution to the EM field is zero, the magnetic field of a point charge can be written entirely in terms of the current density, and thus one could conclude that the current density is the sole thing responsible for the field produced.  However as your question is phrased, the CURL of the magnetic field is determined by both the time derivative and current density. Ofcourse with a zero homogenous solution the former is a result of the charge/J density,

Comment: But in general this may  not actually be the case, both terms are equally important when considering maxwells equations in general,  there are charge -field interactions that "inform" the field-field interaction ( so you could say they are causal ) and there are field-field interactions independant of the positions of charges and currents ( homogenous solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose one can explain the shape of the above magnetic field from the following Maxwell's Equation:
>
> $\nabla\times \boldsymbol{B} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{E}}{\partial t}$
>
> The current component $\boldsymbol{J}$ is not needed since we have a lone charge moving in space.

Actually it's the opposite. Without $\mathbf J$ due to moving charge, there would not be such electric and magnetic field, moving together with the charged body, concentrated around it. The Ampere-Maxwell equation relating magnetic and electric field has also another term $\mu_0 \mathbf J$ and only then it is valid everywhere.

Outside the charged body, the equation can be written without the $\mu_0 \mathbf J$ term, but then it alone does not imply magnitude and direction of these fields; this simplified equation (mathematically, "homogeneous equation") allows for infinity of different fields, including such that both fields vanish. The fact they do not vanish is due to charge and current being present at the point where this simplified equation does not hold.

There is no additional electric field, the field of a moving charge is compressed in direction of motion (Lorentz contraction) and thus has non-zero curl.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a small neighbourhood without charges: $\delta x$ $\delta y$ $\delta z $ around a point $P$, and during a small time interval $\delta t$. If $\mathbf E$ changes during $\delta t$, then $\mathbf B$ is not constant over the neighbourhood, because its spatial derivatives changes (curl not zero).

On the other hand, it is possible to imagine that $\mathbf E$ only changes with time, but it is spatially constant around $P$. In this case $\mathbf B$ doesn't change during $\delta t$.

Of course, the most general case (as that resulting from the OP moving charge) is both fields changing with time. The homogeneous Maxwell equations tell that they also must change in space. The mutual relation between fields in that small neighbourhood obeys the homogeneous Maxwell equations.

Answer (score 0):

Changing B (E) fields don't cause E (B) fields. They are both generated by charges, currents, and their time derivatives such that the curl of E (B) is proportional to the time derivative of B (E).

To analyze the above problem, you can consider a a charge:

$$ q(t, \vec r) = q\delta(x-vt) $$

and a current density

$$ j(t, \vec r) = q(t, \vec r)v\hat x $$

but that is hard. Just take a Coulomb point charge field, B=0,  and Lorentz transform it.

Comment: I was also told that changing E(or B) fields don't generate B(or E) fields. They only "accompany" each other, such that Maxwell's equations hold true. Of course, the source of E and B are charges or currents. Could you please point out where in my question have I insinuated a causal relationship between E and B fields?

Comment: Dissagree slightly, how would you explain non zero solutions solutions to the homogenous wave equation.  And yes OP: Changing electric and magnetic fields coexist, also search up Lienard-wiechert potentials to analyse the extra E field the coexist with the changing magnetic field a moving point charge

Comment: @ Kraken "The current component is not needed since we have a lone charge moving in space".....but that lone moving charge is a  current / changing current density generating the magnetic field.

Comment: @jensenpaull not sure, but I'll go with boundary conditions, e.g. and empty source free volume of space has microwaves in it, but a la Jefimenko's Eqs, those can be traced back to CMB on the past light cone 13.7868 +/-0.020 billion years afo.